# Finding the position of scroll bar using javascript

Tags: javascript, scrollbar

I need to hint my user that there are some useful results on next page as soon as he crosses half of the width of my webpage(home). For this, I wish to know the exact position of the scroll bar , so , that as soon as the position of the scroll bar goes after 50% , I can trigger some javascript function to do the same.

I have encircled the scroll bar in the picture whose position, I have to find out

[image]

Also, if we can't find out the position of scroll bar, please tell me some alternate method to do the same !

Thanks !!

Comment: I don't know for what purpose you need the position of the scroll bar. But keep in mind that all touch devices and all computers with OS X 10.7 or higher won't show a scroll bar by default. It's visible only for a short time  during scrolling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't find the position of the scrollbar since it's not a part of the DOM but what you can do is determine the position. Since I don't know how to do it with vanilla JavaScript I'll give you a jQuery example:

```
var scrollTop = $("body").scrollTop(); // pixels scrolled from top
var documentHeight = $(document).height(); // the height of the document

if(scrollTop >= documentHeight / 2){
    // 50%+ scrolled
}
```